# Can Xcode installed from a dmg file to updated automatically

Tags: mac-appstore, xcode

I wanted to install the latest Xcode 6.1 from here https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#, because a lot of things cannot compile with Xcode 6.0.1 on Yosemite. However, I want to know whether this will force me to manually update Xcode in the future. Can the Xcode installed from other sources benefit from auto update in the App Store? Or is there builtin updater in Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

if you instal Xcode from the dmg file it will not update automatically. you have to download the updates and install manualy. 
or download the new version from app store once